# Running rest calls parallel in spring rest

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, parallel-processing, spring-rest

I am working on Spring-Rest application in which we have a request(Parent request) having few requests inside it(child request(varies from 10-50)).
We have to call another API with those child request and recieve response/request (child response) which we have to integrate into main response(parent response).
I am able to code upto this scenario but the problem is that it is taking too much time and that makes our API slow.
I am looking out for a way by which we can make call parallel so that the API can perform faster.

I have already used parallel stream with custom thread but the problem which I am encountering is that I am not able to store any value when I am doing

```
childRequests
    .prallelStream()
    .forEach((request) -> 
            {my logic to call other api and store result into childResponse }
    )
```

I am getting that "childResponse needs to be final or effectively final"

Comment: Of what type is your "childResponse"?
It is correct that your childResponse must be effective final, so initialised before the stream operation. But you should be able to allocate e.g. an empty ConcurrentLinkedQueue of results before your stream and store all possible results in it. Careful: your result list should support parallel interaction otherwise you might loose added results on parallel interactions.

Comment: My childResponses are also a custom object.

Comment: `childResponse needs to be final or effectively final`.

Inside Lambda, you cannot use a variable that is not-effectively-final.
I.e. its value can be set once, it does not have to be declared as 'final', but after the value is set, it should not be changed.

So, use it as a local variable within the Lambda.  And then add it to a global List or Map of 'ChildResponse' objects.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be some kind of identifier for each `childRequest`, to distinguish between the responses.  A specific response belongs to which request.

If request has an identifier that is a sequence of numbers like 0 to 10 or 0 to 50, then you can use a `List<ChildResponse>` to hold responses per request id.

E.g.

```
final List<ChildResponse> childResponses = new Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
childRequests
    .prallelStream()
    .forEach((request) -> 
            {my logic to call other api and store result into childResponse }
            childResponses.add(request.getId(), childResponse);
    )
```

or
If there is some String request identifier for each request, you can have a `Map<String, ChildResponse>` to store the responses.

```
final Map<String, ChildResponse> childResponses = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
childRequests
    .prallelStream()
    .forEach((request) -> 
            {my logic to call other api and store result into childResponse }
            childResponses.put(request.getId(), childResponse);
    )
```

And after that, you can go through the child requests again in a sequence (not parallel) and do whatever you have to do with the child responses in that sequence (if sequence is important to do whatever further is needed to be done).